# Retrieve data with bad date format - Snowflake

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

A json data seems to have a bad date format, eg - '2019-07'. The correct date format would look something like this, eg - '2019-12-30T03:47:23.962'

I am trying to retrieve the whole record which has this bad data. I am using variations of the following query, but nothing seems to be working -

eg - retrieves all the files which  has the below dates in it, as expected

> SELECT * FROM data  where data.date LIKE '%2019-07%';

eg2- does not retrieve any data

> SELECT * FROM data  where data.date LIKE '2019-07 %';

Any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: Is it because there is a space character after 07? So how about using LIKE '2019-07%' ?

Comment: Can you share an example of the json please?

Comment: Is your JSON stored in a variant field? If yes, then you need to use this [dot notation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html#dot-notation) format. Basically between column and first level you need to use **<column>:<level1_elem>**.

Comment: Having got the field value using the dot notation, you could then use TRY_TO_DATE to determine if the field contains a valid date

Comment: @NickW -  Using TRY_TO_DATE throws following error, 
Error - SQL compilation error: Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types VARIANT and DATE

Comment: @GokhanAtil:  Using - LIKE '2019-07%' gives me all other records that has date matching this format - 2019-07-DD HH:MI:SS format

Comment: @Marcel
 Example JSON, name - **data**
{
  "id": "5475",
  "brand": "AAAA",
  "date": "2019-12-30T03:47:23.962"
}

**Example query** - Select * from data where data:date like '2019-07 %';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Error-handling Conversion Functions - TRY_CAST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#label-try-conversion-functions):

> Conversion functions with a TRY_ prefix are special versions of their respective conversion functions. **These functions return a NULL value instead of raising an error when the conversion can not be performed**

```
select * 
from data 
where try_cast(data:date::string as date) is null;
```

Comment: I think your solution should work. But I am concluding that my data might be more messed up than I am anticipating. The above query does not yield any results in my case still , but I know the above query would work in an ideal situation. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lakm If it does not yields resuslt, and you are sure yoy have correct data then explicit date format is way to go. `where try_to_date(data:date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FF3') is null`